# How to change the width of attribute columns within android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem that the columns on the left side are sometimes too small in the android studio so that I cannot read the whole attribute name. Even if I increase the whole width of the attributes panel, it increases the size of the right side of the columns mostly. Is there any way to change only the size of the left columns? (e.g. in the picture the layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle)
[image: left and right columns of attributes example]

Answer (score 0):

As, mentioned by you, I got no way to just increase the **Left Column**. But, when I increased width of the attribute panel, both **Left & Right Column** widths increased. I am using updated **Android Studio 3.5**

Please check below images.

**Partially Visible**
[image: Here, the attribute is hidden]

**Fully Visible**
[image: the attribute is visible]